# Send keys in Windows 10 IoT

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi2, iot, windows-10-iot-core

I develop a capacitive I2C keyboard for a Raspberry Pi 2 with Windows 10 IoT, so when my I2C controller detects a key stroke I need to send a key to the current page.

How can I send keys?

In windows forms I have used:

```
SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
```

Comment: What do you mean? If it's your own application, you can directly modify the UI or perform some action when you detect a keystroke. You *don't* need to send any keystrokes. Have you put all business logic in the screen's event handlers perhaps? That a *bad* design even for desktop apps. You should separate *actions* from the UI, especially in this case where the UI no longer generates events

Comment: Is this still the case? Did you get round it in the end?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but it is not allowed in UWP due to some APIs restriction to be called only by user interaction. Refer this forum: http://msdev.developer-works.com/article/29629099/%5BUWP%5DIs+SendKeys+available+within+Windows+Universal+App%3F

Instead you can programmatically write text to the textboxes like:

```
// To simulate key 'A' and 'B'
Textbox1.Text += 'A';
Textbox1.Text += 'B';

// To simulate backspace if Textbox contains any character
if (Textbox1.Text.Length > 0)
{
    Textbox1.Text = Textbox1.Text.Remove(Textbox1.Text.Length - 1);
}
```

Problem with this snippet is, you can't simulate special key like ALT, CTRL, F1-F12, Shift and WinKey.

Hope this will help you to resolve your issues a bit.